# Probability of sum of normal distributions under threshold, given that each distribution is under a known threshold

Tags: probability, truncated-normal-distribution

Say we have $k$ mutually independent normal random variables $M_1,\ldots,M_k$ where $M_i = \mathcal N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$. We have another normal random variable $R = \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ that is independent to each $M_i$. Let $T_1,\ldots,T_k$ be positive reals. What, then, is the following conditional probability?

$$\mathbb P \left( \sum M_i \leq R \;\middle|\; \bigcap M_i\leq T_i \right)$$

This comes from a project I'm working on in the field of systems engineering and design; unfortunately, I've been unable to come up with something elegant. Obviously a numerical solution works, or there is a $k+1$th order integral over a $k$-simplex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To conform to the standard notational convention of upper case for random variables and lower case for fixed vales, I am going to refer to the bounding values as $t_1,...,t_k$ (instead of the upper-case letter) in my answer.*

For this kind of problem it is simplest to first consider the case where the relevant bounds $t_1,...,t_k,r$ are fixed values and then you can use the law of total probability to marginalise over a distribution for a random variable $R$.  That is the way I will proceed here.

Conditioning on the upper-bounds for the random variables does not induce any dependence between them (since the bounds are fixed values)$^\dagger$ so ultimately this computation is a convolution of truncated normal distributions.  To facilitate analysis of this problem, we will let $M_i^* \sim \text{TruncN}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2, t_i)$ denote a random variable with a truncated normal distribution with upper-bound $t_i$.  We will also define the quantities:

$$w_i \equiv - \log \Phi \bigg( \frac{t_i-\mu_i}{\sigma_i} \bigg).$$

The characteristic function for this random variable is:

$$\begin{align}
\phi_{M_i^*} (t)
&\equiv \mathbb{E}(\exp(it M_i^*)) \\[24pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(\exp(it M_i) | M_i \leqslant t_i ) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{1}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp(itm) \cdot \text{N}(m | \mu_i, \sigma_i^2) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp(itm) \cdot \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{m-\mu_i}{\sigma_i} \bigg)^2 \bigg) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp \bigg( itm - \frac{m^2 - 2 \mu_i m + \mu_i^2}{2 \sigma_i^2} \bigg) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma_i^2} \bigg[ m^2 - 2(\mu_i + it \sigma_i^2) m + \mu_i^2 \bigg] \bigg) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2)}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)}  \\[6pt]
&\quad \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma_i^2} \bigg[ m^2 - 2(\mu_i + it \sigma_i^2) m + (\mu_i^2 + 2 it \mu_i \sigma_i^2 - t^2 \sigma_i^4) \bigg] \bigg) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2)}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \exp \bigg( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma_i^2} (m - \mu_i - it \sigma_i^2)^2 \bigg) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2)}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t_i} \text{N}(m|\mu_i + it \sigma_i^2, \sigma_i^2) \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\exp(- it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2)}{\Phi((t_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)} \cdot \Phi((t_i-\mu_i - it \sigma_i^2)/\sigma_i) \\[18pt]
&= \exp(w_i - it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2) \cdot \Phi((t_i-\mu_i - it \sigma_i^2)/\sigma_i). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

To facilitate further analysis, let $\dot{M} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^k M_i$ denote the sum of the random variables at issue and let $\dot{M}^* \equiv \sum_{i=1}^k M_i^*$ denote the sum of the truncated versions.  Since $M_i^* \sim \{ M_i | M_i \leqslant t_i \}$ and since there is no inducement of dependence between the variables by applying the fixed upper bounds, the conditional characteristic function of the sum is:

$$\begin{align}
\phi_{\dot{M}| \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t}} (t)
&\equiv \mathbb{E}(\exp(it \dot{M}) | M_1 \leqslant t_1, ... , M_k \leqslant t_k ) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{E}(\exp(it M_i) | M_i \leqslant t_i) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \phi_{M_i^*} (t) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \exp(w_i - it \mu_i + t^2 \sigma_i^2/2) \cdot \Phi((t_i-\mu_i - it \sigma_i^2)/\sigma_i)  \\[6pt]
&= \exp \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^k w_i - it \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i + \frac{t^2}{2} \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 \bigg) \prod_{i=1}^k \Phi \bigg( \frac{t_i-\mu_i - it \sigma_i^2}{\sigma_i} \bigg) . \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Applying the inverse Fourier transform to this function then yields the conditional density function for $\dot{M}| \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t}$, which allows computation of the probability of interest for a fixed upper bound $r$.  To do the calculation for a random upper-bound $R$
you can add an additional step to marginalise over the distribution of this random variable.  Still computationally intensive, but preferable to an integral of arbitrarily high dimension.

---

$^\dagger$ In the main body of the answer it is asserted that the imposition of fixed upper bounds does not induce dependence between the random variables $M_1,...,M_k$.  We demonstrate that property here.  Since $M_1,....,M_k$ are assumed to be mutually independent, their joint density can be written as a product of marginal densities:

$$f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m}) = \prod_{i=1}^k f(M_i = m_i).$$

We can therefore write the joint conditional density (imposing the fixed upper bound conditions) as:

$$\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m} | \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t})
&= f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m} | M_1 \leqslant t_1,...,M_k \leqslant t_k) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m}, M_1 \leqslant t_1,...,M_k \leqslant t_k)}{\mathbb{P}(M_1 \leqslant t_1,...,M_k \leqslant t_k)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m}) \cdot \mathbb{I}( m_1 \leqslant t_1,...,m_k \leqslant t_k)}{\mathbb{P}(M_1 \leqslant t_1,...,M_k \leqslant t_k)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^k f(M_i = m_i) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{I}( m_i \leqslant t_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}(M_i \leqslant t_i)} \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{f(M_i = m_i) \cdot \mathbb{I}( m_i \leqslant t_i)}{\mathbb{P}(M_i \leqslant t_i)} \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{f(M_i = m_i, M_i \leqslant t_i)}{\mathbb{P}(M_i \leqslant t_i)} \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k f(M_i = m_i| M_i \leqslant t_i). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Using the law of the unconscious statistician we then have:

$$\begin{align}
\phi_{\dot{M}| \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t}} (t)
&= \mathbb{E}(\exp(it (M_1+...+M_k)) |  \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t}) \\[18pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp(it (m_1+...+m_k)) f(\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m} |  \mathbf{M} \leqslant \mathbf{t}) \ d\mathbf{m} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} ... \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^k \exp(it m_i) \bigg) \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^k f(M_i = m_i| M_i \leqslant t_i) \bigg) \ dm_1 ... dm_k \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(it m_i) f(M_i = m_i| M_i \leqslant t_i) \ dm_i \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{E}(\exp(it M_i) | M_i \leqslant t_i). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: The "equality" $E[\exp(it(M_1 + \cdots + M_k))|M_1 \leq t_1, \ldots, M_k \leq t_k) = \sum_{i = 1}^k E[\exp(itM_i|M_i \leq t_i)]$ is probably not right.   In addition, your answer seems did not take into account the random variable $R$ in OP's question.

Comment: I need to read this much closer, but for now I need to say that $R$ is in fact a random variable, and $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ are often given as random variables in other contexts. In this case, you can take them to be trivial random variables.

Comment: I had also hoped for an O(1) solution, but that may not be possible... I'd be curious why not?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: Sorry, I meant to use the product, not the sum --- edited.

Comment: @Ben Really appreciate the answer. Will mark as accepted once I have personally verified every step. Do you have any intuition for whether or not a closed form solution is possible to this query?

Comment: @MatthewAnderson: The characteristic function of interest is quite complicated (and not in closed form itself) and it is likely that it will become even more complicated when inverted by the inverse Fourier transform, so my intuition is that there is no closed form solution.  You would need to employ numerical methods to perform the inverse Fourier transform and the subsequent steps.